# asp.net caused mysql 99% usage

Tags: mysql, cpu

I have an asp.net application which use Mysql. I test it on testing server running MySQL. When the application is running, it consumes 40% of cpu. I run the same code in production server which also running MySQL, now it consumes 99% of cpu usage. What setting in MySQL config will affect the CPU consuming level? Because I am running the same code but the result is totally different.

Here is the config of high cpu usage mysql:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=28800
wait_timeout=28800

port=3306

datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data

character-set-server=utf8

default-storage-engine=INNODB


sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE
general-log=1
general_log_file="EC2AMAZ-SSAVRCC.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="EC2AMAZ-SSAVRCC-slow.log"
long_query_time=10

log-error="EC2AMAZ-SSAVRCC.err"


server-id=1


secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=151

query_cache_size=0

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=2G

thread_cache_size=10

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=4G

key_buffer_size = 10M

read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6144M

innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_thread_concurrency=33


innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8


innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000


innodb_open_files=300


innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1


innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

 join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=10M

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=4161


query_cache_type=0

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Here is the code of less cpu usage mysql:

```
[mysqld]
```

port=3306

datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE

general-log=0

general_log_file="c:\MySQL_LOG\WIN-9BPM7TSIO9C.log"

slow-query-log=0

slow_query_log_file="WIN-9BPM7TSIO9C-slow.log"

long_query_time=1

log-error="WIN-9BPM7TSIO9C.err"

server-id=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=151

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=16M

thread_cache_size=10

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M

key_buffer_size=8M

read_buffer_size=0

read_rnd_buffer_size=0

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M

innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_thread_concurrency=17

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_open_files=300

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=100M

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=4161

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000

net_read_timeout = 999999
net_write_timeout = 999999

Comment: High CPU means missing index(es) and/or poorly formulated queries.  See this for how to find the naughty queries:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 1):

There may be various causes for this difference, but the first thing that comes to mind is that the second configuration is tuned to use less memory (e.g. innodb_buffer_pool_size, tmp_table_size). Therefore, it may need to use more disk IO to process the same amount of data. CPU has to wait for disk operations to complete before it may proceed to the next chunk of data and hence it becomes underutilized if there are lots of them.

You may try to confirm this conjecture by establishing disk performance monitoring approximately like described in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor-disk-counters-explained/ .

And I would say 100% utilization of one CPU core is a normal thing with bulk operations in MySQL. The engine doesn’t have much parallelization so it generally can’t use more than one core per session. Lower utilization during bulk operations (e.g. mass insert) means there’s non-CPU bottleneck that needs addressing (because it makes the same operation take longer). You may try to figure out if that’s the case by comparing the time it takes the test script to complete in the two environments.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the General Log is turned on with the 'slow' production machine.  Compare your test to production ini files and you should recognize many 'capacity' variables that are significantly different and will cause the production to consume more resources.